# "[AppName] stopped working" when I try to run my app on an AVD emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm working on an app and the first thing I did was make a contact list structure. This is the video I started with as a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esDWSfBa-oc

It all went well until I got an error that could have only been fixed by changing `cursor.getColumnIndex()` to `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow()` as seen in the (MainActivity) code below:

```
private void getContactList() {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String sort = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+"ASC";

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                uri, null, null, null, sort
        );

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
                ));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                ));
                Uri uriPhone = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
                String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                        + " =?";
                Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        uriPhone, null, selection,
                        new String[]{id}, null
                );
                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                    String number = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                    ));
                    ContactModel model = new ContactModel();
                    model.setName(name);
                    model.setNumber(number);
                    arrayList.add(model);
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MainAdapter(this,arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

If I remove the "OrThrow" indications in `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow()`, it will give me an error with no visible fixes, telling me to ask for feedback online. Very strange considering I did everything exactly as in the video and any errors are either by some typo that I haven't found yet or from the app itself being somehow different, in terms of libraries or preset adjustments, which I'm not sure at all.

After having watched the full video and finishing the initial app structure, the app would just not open, and, after rewatching the video and thinking I had to decline contact access (which in fact wasn't the case, the video was just showing what happens if we refuse to allow access, because the contact access is obviously needed), it would work but it wouldn't show contacts, of course.

Error in the logcat:

```
2021-10-18 17:43:21.130 12998-12998/com.example.wolfix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.wolfix, PID: 12998
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wolfix/com.app.wolfix.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: display_nameASC (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT 0 AS last_time_contacted, phonetic_name, custom_ringtone, contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts, pinned, photo_id, photo_file_id, contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, agg_presence.chat_capability AS contact_chat_capability, contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, display_name_alt, sort_key_alt, in_visible_group, starred, contacts_status_updates.status_label AS contact_status_label, phonebook_label, is_user_profile, has_phone_number, display_name_source, phonetic_name_style, send_to_voicemail, lookup, phonebook_label_alt, contact_last_updated_timestamp, photo_uri, phonebook_bucket, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, display_name, sort_key, photo_thumb_uri, agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, in_default_directory, 0 AS times_contacted, _id, name_raw_contact_id, phonebook_bucket_alt FROM view_contacts LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (_id = agg_presence.presence_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id) WHERE ((1)) ORDER BY display_nameASC
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: display_nameASC (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT 0 AS last_time_contacted, phonetic_name, custom_ringtone, contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts, pinned, photo_id, photo_file_id, contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, agg_presence.chat_capability AS contact_chat_capability, contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, display_name_alt, sort_key_alt, in_visible_group, starred, contacts_status_updates.status_label AS contact_status_label, phonebook_label, is_user_profile, has_phone_number, display_name_source, phonetic_name_style, send_to_voicemail, lookup, phonebook_label_alt, contact_last_updated_timestamp, photo_uri, phonebook_bucket, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, display_name, sort_key, photo_thumb_uri, agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, in_default_directory, 0 AS times_contacted, _id, name_raw_contact_id, phonebook_bucket_alt FROM view_contacts LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (_id = agg_presence.presence_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id) WHERE ((1)) ORDER BY display_nameASC
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:186)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:472)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1183)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1115)
2021-10-18 17:43:21.130 12998-12998/com.example.wolfix E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1071)
        at com.app.wolfix.MainActivity.getContactList(MainActivity.java:52)
        at com.app.wolfix.MainActivity.checkPermission(MainActivity.java:43)
        at com.app.wolfix.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
            ... 11 more
```

I tried:

- adding contacts in the emulator (couldn't find how, and when I tried connecting to my Google account, it still wouldn't let me have contact access);
- adding contacts programmatically (not even that would work, probably having to do with the contact access as well);
- revisiting the code, specially the aforementioned "OrThrow" incident part, to see if that had anything to do with it;
- check if it the problem was in the emulator itself (couldn't take any conclusions).

I still think the problem is in the emulator, I just don't know how to exactly fix it.

I'm not entirely new to the world of programming, I'm just working on a school project and Android Studio, being the app I'm using, is still something I'm learning and adapting to.

Any help would be appreciated, and even if the mistake is in the code or the emulated software, I hope you understand I'm still not completely fond of it. In case more code is needed, I am able to do so, but, like I said, most of the code was taken from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esDWSfBa-oc, so anything there is here, other than the aforementioned changes of course.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error log shows

> ```
>  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: display_nameASC
> ```

Here `ASC` is for an ascending sort order. You need to put a space between the column name and `ASC`

```
  String sort = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I have one question though: considering this text is preceded by "Caused by:", does that mean all errors are always followed by that? Just asking so I don't have the same question again, since it's most likely the case and it does make more sense.

Comment: Mostly yeah, you can say that.
If you see your stacktrace, the first line has it mentioned too.
`java.lang.RuntimeException: ... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: display_nameASC (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): ..`

Comment: I'm going to try that tomorrow. Thanks for the help!