# How do I make a certain component have a relative layout with another component outside of its linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

So, the title may be confusing, but to put it in context:

**I have an ImageButton component in my app display that should be on the opposite side of my ImageView, lined up perfectly, and to repeat this for any other item on the same list.**

My question and doubt itself is how to do this when the ImageButton in this case is inside a LinearLayout while the ImageView is outside of it. Is there like a code line that can connect an outside element to a LinearLayout inside element.

Here's how my display looks:
[item_contact.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRokI.png)

The blue rectangle, being the LinearLayout, means everything inside belongs to it, but the call button looks to be the on the other side of the user pic, which is not inside the LinearLayout, which is what I wanted, the problem is this:
[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBe64.png)

Each of the TextViews are above and below both the user picture and the call button, but because they both also belong to the LinearLayout, it's obvious it's because of the latter.

Now I tried fixing the problem by simply adding the user picture to the LinearLayout, which seems like the obvious answer, but I needed to be sure, because my call button isn't correctly aligned to the right:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/call_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="248dp"
            android:background="#1072E1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/call"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My ImageButton's "right alignment" was only done with the manual positioning of the `android:layout_marginStart` which I set to 248dp by attempts. Surely there's a better way to do this, but I've yet to find a solution that works.

Lastly, there's also the aforementioned problem: I can't seem to fix the LinearLayout issue without having to backtrack the progress I've done and use new code lines or already existing ones to resolve the issue.

So:

- How can I "connect" two components, one inside a LinearLayout and another not, with or without the use of constraints and/or RelativeLayouts, and do I really have to insert the outside component to the LinearLayout;
- How can I forcefully align a component to the right without having to manually push it with margin inputs (attempts);
- Is there a way to know exactly how to connect a component to another by using constraints accurately, so it repeats that process through the entire contact list?.

I would really like if someone could answer at least one of the listed questions or, even better, resolve one of the most developed questions, where I show some images of reference.
Maybe even a suited tutorial for my case in specific that explains the ways of designing the layout of an app.

If more information is needed, I will gladly help, and I'll also try to answer to every response I can get.

Also, in case you're curious, here's my last question about the same app (already resolved):

["[AppName] stopped working" when I try to run my app on an AVD emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619969/appname-stopped-working-when-i-try-to-run-my-app-on-an-avd-emulator)

(Keep in mind that the problem at hand in this question has barely anything to do with this one.)

Comment: stop using linear and even relative layouts and make use of constraint layout

Comment: The choice to use LinearLayout here is pretty bad here I think. I assume you don't really want the first textview to be above the button and the other below it, but actually the two textviews together be next to the button. You should drop the linearlayout and figure it out with constraints, as I can see they are actually in a ConstraintLayout already

Comment: Alright, then I'll just use the ConstraintLayout as a method here and see what I can achieve. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's been a problem though, when I try to remove the LinearLayout, it says "This view is not contrained vertically." Each one has a different explanation. Should I try to add all the LinearLayout attributes until the error is fixed?